# Binding GridView to <li>

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to bind gridview with li such that the data populated will all have li tags?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_foodList" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_GetFoodNotEntered"
        OnDataBound="GridView_foodList_DataBound" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#222222"
        BorderColor="#FFA8B0" BorderWidth="2px" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemStyle BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="70px" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="PRICE" HeaderText="Price">
                <ItemStyle BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="70px" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
</Columns></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You can use ListView instead of GridView. Because ListView support more customization than GridView. Check this article [Alternating styles in ListView without AlternatingItemTemplate](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/alternating-styles-in-listview-without-alternatingitemtemplate)

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET `GridView` control generates a table.If you want to generate something more custom like an ordered or unordered list you should use the [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx) control.

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class aaa_useRepeater : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = GetData();

        Repeater1.DataSource = list;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    private List<Prod> GetData()
    {

        var p1 = new Prod { ID = 0, Name = "Product 1" };
        var p2 = new Prod { ID = 1, Name = "Product 2" };
        var p3 = new Prod { ID = 2, Name = "Product 3" };
        var p4 = new Prod { ID = 3, Name = "Product 4" };

        var list = new List<Prod> { p1, p2, p3, p4 };
        return list;
    }
}

public class Prod
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><%# Eval("Name") %></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

**Output:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Product 1</li>
    <li>Product 2</li>
    <li>Product 3</li>
    <li>Product 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the correct approach, perhaps expand upon it to display name and price, as per the OPs example.